# java - method return type confusion

Tags: java, return

I'm trying to return a 2D matrix from a function. Eclipse complains about the return type of the function

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class myClass {

    private static String inFile = "myfile.csv";

    private String[][] readCsv() {
        File file1 = new File(inFile);
        if (file1.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File " + inFile + " exists. length : " + inFile.length());
        } else {
            System.out.println("File " + inFile + " does not exist!");
        }

        try {
            // Read all
            CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(inFile)));
            List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();

            // Convert to 2D array
            String[][] dataArr = new String[list.size()][];
            dataArr = list.toArray(dataArr);

            return dataArr;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Do something with mistake or ignore
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myClass mc = new myClass();
        String[][] csvContents = mc.readCsv();

        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(csvContents[k]));
        }
    }

}
```

The error eclipse tells me is `This method must return a result of type String[][]`. The value being returned, `dataArr` is of type `String[][]` & the method `readCsv` is instructed to return `String[][]`.

I can't quite figure out where the mistake is.

Comment: You're not returning anything when an exception is thrown.

Comment: It may be potentially advantageous to declare the Exceptions that may occur in this method in the method summary. That way, you don't need a try catch and you don't need to return a bogus value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to return something in case the try block throws an exception:

```
public String[][] myMethod() {
    String[][] arr = new String[1][];
    try {
        arr = methodThatCanThrowException(); // If this method throws an exception
        return arr;                          // this return will not execute
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}

    return arr;                              // Return something after the try/catch block
}
```

How you handle this is up to you, you can either return some default value or perhaps `null`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you Marv

Answer (score 3):

The method must return a `String[][]` in every possible branch. Here, you only return it from the `try` - if it doesn't complete successfully and an exception is thrown, the `catch` will complete without returning anything, thus the error. You could just `return` after the try-catch block, like @Marv suggested, but IMHO, the proper Java-way would be to just allow the exception to be thrown up out of the method instead of catching it:

```
// should probably throw something more specific
private String[][] readCsv() throws Exception { 
    // Read all
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(new File(inFile)));
    List<String[]> list = csvReader.readAll();

    // Convert to 2D array
    String[][] dataArr = new String[list.size()][];
    dataArr = list.toArray(dataArr);

    return dataArr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't returning **anything** in the event that an exception is caught in `readCsv`.  You need to return something here.

```
catch (Exception ex) {
        // Do something with mistake or ignore
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return SOMETHING;
    }
```

Comment: 1) Compiler error is occurring because you must explicity `return dataArr;` *FROM EACH POSSIBLE CODE PATH*.  2) One alternative is `return null;`.  Another alternative is to initialize `String[][] dataArr = null;` outside of your try/catch block.  3) Arguably the *best* solution is to allow readCsv to throw the exception, and let your higher-level code handle it.

Comment: @paulsm4 Is this directed at me or the OP?  There is no best solution, it depends on how the OP wants the method to work.

Answer (score 2):

When an exception is caught and the code function continues, there is no return value